# ubuntu dist update python package failed

Tags: 20.04, package-management

ı was upgrading my distribution . But while it was upgrading i got package failed error like this. I tried eveything but i could not find any solutions. Do you have any suggestions?

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 blueman : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Depends: gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 but it is not installed
 dbus-user-session : Depends: dbus (>= 1.12.20-1ubuntu3)
 dbus-x11 : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-1ubuntu3) but 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1 is installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.24) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.20-1ubuntu3)
 gpgsm : Depends: libksba8 (>= 1.5.0) but 1.3.5-2 is installed
 libpython3-dev : Depends: libpython3.9-dev (>= 3.9.4-0~) but it is not installed
 lz4 : Depends: liblz4-1 (= 1.9.2-2) but 1.9.3-1build1 is installed
 onboard : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Recommends: gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 but it is not installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.9.4-1 is installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-netifaces : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf23 (>= 3.12.4) but it is not installed
                    Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-psutil : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-simplejson : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-talloc : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
                  Depends: libpython3.9 (>= 3.9.1) but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.1.3-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) but 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:7.1.3-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) but it is not installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
               Depends: python3.9 but it is not installed
               Depends: libpython3.9 (>= 3.9.1) but it is not installed
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.9-venv (>= 3.9.4-0~) but it is not installed
                Depends: python3 (= 3.9.4-1) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
                Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.9.4-0~) but 3.8.5-1~20.04.1 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: libimobiledevice6 (>= 1.3.0) but 1.2.1~git20191129.9f79242-1build1 is installed
                     Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu4) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: python3.9 but it is not installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu4) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu4) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).enter code here
```

Comment: Please share the output from `apt-cache policy blueman python3 dbus libreoffice` . If long - use pastebin.

Comment: Output of the command- https://www.paste.tc/basliksiz-809

Comment: You have mixed repositories of focal (20.04 LTS) and groovy (20.10). Is it was planned? Please share full output of `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list ; cat /etc/os-release` .  Which version do  you really plan to use?

Comment: actually ı do not have any plan ı just used first this: sudo su
sed 's/focal/hirsute/g' /etc/apt/sources.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hirsute.list
apt update
apt dist-upgrade

then i got error while it was updating then i used this:

rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hirsute.list
sed 's/focal/groovy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/groovy.list
apt update
apt dist-upgrade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix packages on currently installed system

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If you really want to upgrade to non-LTS 9-months supported-version (say to have many unnecessary upgrades to next LTS like: 20.04 LTS → 20.10 → 21.04 → *21.10* → *22.04 LTS*), then allow such upgrade process and run it with supported correct method

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-focal

sudo sed -i "s/^Prompt=lts/Prompt=normal/" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
sudo sed -i "s/^Prompt=never/Prompt=normal/" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

update-manager -c # in GUI or
# sudo do-release-upgrade # in terminal
```

Note: the last command should be run twice - first for 20.04 LTS → 20.10 and second for 20.10 → 21.04 . For the latter you may need to provide extra `-d` option.

Comment: When i was doing first two step, at the step 2 i got this error again. https://www.paste.tc/basliksiz-810 should i pass step 3?

Comment: You still have not provided the output of `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list ; cat /etc/os-release` . Please do this.

Comment: I applied grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list ; cat /etc/os-release this and turn back step two i got same error.  paste.tc/basliksiz-810

Comment: Again, I need the full output of `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list ; cat /etc/os-release` to understand next steps!

Comment: @N0rbert  when higher versions are installed the in focal available like form groovy is not apt-pinning also needed to revert it to lower version?

Comment: @N0rbert output of the command. https://www.paste.tc/basliksiz-811

Comment: @nobody thanks. The system is now in very bad state, so we need to pin current release. Step is updated, please test it,

Comment: I did updated steps i got this error:  https://www.paste.tc/basliksiz-813

Before this step i did not get any error.

Comment: So we are now stuck. Then please backup your system first and prepare for more experiments. You have chosen this way, not us.

Comment: @N0rbert okey, we can try other ways.

Comment: At first try what apt-get recommends to you - run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` .

Comment: @N0rbert i again tried step 2 from begining of sudo apt-get install aptitude then everything works i did not get any error. What should we check it is done or not?

Comment: some sources are double. Please move  file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/groovy.list`   to another location like a folder in your $HOME.

Comment: I applied mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/groovy.list $Home then what should i do?

Comment: Answer updated. Use standard mechanism without `sed` .

Comment: @N0rbert thanks a lot i applied everything and did not get any error. It seems fine.

Comment: Great, so you can accept my answer using checkmark in the left of answer.